# Angular js $watch on multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array

hello friends below are my array.

data.php file

```
$array = array(
   '0' => array(
            'id' = 1,
            'name' = 'test',
            'key' = array(
                       '0' = 'key1',
                       '1' = 'key2',
                       '2' = 'key3'
                    )
         ),
   '1' => array(
            'id' = 3,
            'name' = 'test3',
            'key' = array(
                       '0' = 'key7',
                       '1' = 'key8',
                       '2' = 'key9'
                    )
         ),
     '2' => array(
            'id' = 15,
            'name' = 'test30',
            'key' = array(
                       '0' = 'key4',
                       '1' = 'key5',
                       '2' = 'key6'
                    )
         )
);
echo json_encode($array);
```

below are my js code.

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: $rootScope.serverURL+'data.php'}).
  success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $rootScope.simpleData = data;
  }).
  error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

  });

$scope.$watch('page + numPage + simpleData', function() {
    console.log('working');    
},true);
```

this is working fine now i want to set want on "key".

```
$scope.$watch('page + numPage + simpleData.key', function() {
    console.log('not working');    
},true);
```

this code is not working when i write this code like this is working fine.

```
$scope.$watch('page + numPage + simpleData[0].key', function() {
    console.log('working');    
},true);
```

when i write js like it is working fine. angular js watch on key but only for "0" Element.
in the array i have lot's of elements how can i watch on all elements "Key".

please help

thank you

Comment: Clearly, it won't work with `simpleData.key` - there is no such thing.

Comment: @NewDev i edit my question now check.

Comment: What exactly is `simpleData` in your example?

Comment: @NewDev in simpleData i will store my json array please properly see in above code thanks

Comment: @NewDev i edit my code now check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$watch`ing `"simpleData.key"` doesn't work because `$scope.simpleData.key === undefined`.

If you're trying to deep-watch an array, you could add `true` as third parameter to `$watch`, which does a deep-watch, but that comes at a significant cost to performance. Every $digest cycle would have to deep-level compare your array.

```
$watch("simpleData", function(){...}, true);
```

Comment: hey dear thank's for answer this is working but not working with multiple keywords like. $watch("page + numPage + simpleData", function(){...}, true); when i write this is not working please help. thank you so much

Comment: your answer is right but $watch("page + numPage + simpleData", function(){...}, true); this is not working. i pass third parameter true but not work.

Comment: Why would you think that this would work? To watch multiple expressions, use `$watchGroup(["page", "numPage"], function(){...})`, but keep `simpleData` out of it, since `$watchGroup` doesn't do deep-watch.

Comment: this is working thank you so much dear actually i started to learning angular js thank for help men.

Comment: also, read [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) first - it helps. And don't call people here "dear" :) It may be a cultural thing, but it just comes across as odd.